# Make content fit parent container

Tags: css

I decided to apply some .css to stackoverflow.com pages to remove the sidebar because I'm not really interested by it.

```
#sidebar{display:none!important;}
```

The problem I face is the `#mainbar` content doesn't fit anymore the `#content` container and leave a big blank space because of my css
I tried to make `#mainbar` content fit its parent container (`#content`) with

```
#mainbar{width:100%!important;}
```

**How can I make `#mainbar`  full content (question, answers, comments) fit full width of `#content` container?**

Comment: Can you provide more markup  of what you currently have? You may have other classes deciding your width, or margins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#mainbar { width:100%;}
#mainbar #question table { width:100%;}
td.postcell { width:100%;}
#answers { width:100%;}
#answers-header { width: 100%; }
.answer { width: 100%; }
```

A lot of elements have fixed widths it seems!

Comment: `.comments { width:100%; } .answer { width:100%; } .answer table { width: 100%; }` (hope I didn't miss anything)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do the following alongside what you've already tried:

`.post-text { width: 100%; }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set width : 100% to the postcell class

```
.postcell
{
  width : 100%;
}
```

And change width of post-text class :

```
.post-text
{
  width : inherit;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

To `#mainbar` remove the `float:left;` and change `margin` to `margin: 0 auto 0;`

Comment: @Marcin If you are looking to make the answers section 100% width of #content, then that might make things complicated cause a lot of the content has width settings nested down quite a bit, from what I can quickly observe.